# Replace a set of strings with its last digits in a pandas dataframe column

Tags: python, python-3.x

My pandas dataframe has a column with row values equal to either a string value of https://acbedfgid=123456 (Which is supposed to be a hyperlink but is in string) or "No Proposal" depending on the other row values...

If its the former case,I want to replace the entire string with just the last 6 digits(This is always constant) and if its the later, it should be as it is ("No Proposal")

How do I achieve this in pandas

Thank you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try

```
df.loc[df['ColName'].ne('No Proposal'), 'ColName'] = df.loc[df['ColName'].ne('No Proposal'), 'ColName'].str[-6:]
```

or

```
df['ColName'].where(df['ColName'].eq('No Proposal'), lambda x: x['ColName'][-6:], inplace=True)
```

Comment: The First approach gives me the last 6 digits correctly, but when it is supposed to return "No Proposal" , it only gives  "oposal" .

Comment: Yes look at the Code - I just didn't see that your `No Proposal` is written with a spce inbetween and I wrote it without. Just add a space in the `No Proposal`... see last edit